# How to join two tables in PHP - MySQL that match an ID in the second table and still display specific record in table 1?

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin, rdbms

I have two tables (account and restaurant) How can I display all records from two tables but exclude some records?

```
table: account
+-------+----------+------------+
| uid   | name     | role       |
+-------+----------+------------+
|  1    | John     | Admin      |
|  2    | Steve    | Resto_Owner|
|  3    | Bill     | Customer   |
+-------+----------+------------+

table: restaurant
+--------+----------+------------+
|resto_id|  uid     | resto_name |
+--------+----------+------------+
|  1     |   2      |Steve Resto |
+--------+----------+------------+


**This is my Desired Output:** 
+-------+----------+------------+--------------+
| uid   | name     | role       | resto_name   |
+-------+----------+------------+--------------+
|  1    | John     | Admin      |              |
|  2    | Steve    | Resto_Owner| Steve Resto  |
+-------+----------+------------+--------------+
```

**I want to display records from these two tables with the role admin and resto_owner. But also display the resto_name if the role is resto_owner, blank if admin and do not display if customer**

I tried to use INNER JOIN but it only display: **2   Steve   Resto_Owner    Steve Resto** and does NOT display the admin record:

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use left join with conditions

```
 SELECT account_table.uid, account_table.name, account_table.role, restaurant_table.resto_name 
    FROM account account_table LEFT JOIN restaurant restaurant_table
    ON restaurant_table.uid = account_table.uid 
    WHERE account_table.role <> 'Customer' ORDER BY account_table.uid ASC
```

More in https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_left.asp

Comment: I'd just like to ask aside from excluding the role = 'customer' How can I also exclude when or if the resto_name = " " or NULL? Because when I tried to use resto_name NOT NULL OR resto_name <> "" the admin record don't display? Thanks again :)

Comment: In general, with the LEFT JOIN operation, mysql fill null values for missing entries in second table. Therefore, it is impossible to distinguish them in the condition in this query. Depending on the need, you can change the condition to return absolutely all administrators  and  restaurant owners whose restaurant’s name is not null or empty string

... WHERE account_table.role = 'ADMIN' OR (account_table.role = 'Resto_Owner' AND restaurant_table.resto_name IS NOT NULL) ...

Comment: Thank you very much! You're a great help Alexey :)